# coordinating conjunctions

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

*For* is used as an introduction of reason. I consider, the reason of what happened in the first clause should be introduce with For (used as coordinating conjunction) in the second clause.

"She must have been tired, for she fell asleep the moment she inclined her head."
(Nikos Kazantzakis, Report to Greco, 1965)

The above sentence is doing opposite to main idea.

I think it should be written as

she fell asleep the moment she inclined her head, for She must have been tired.
Please elaborate.

Comment: The sentence means: _"We can be certain that she was tired, because she fell asleep the moment she inclined her head."_ You should study the meaning and usage of the English modal verb _must_. Here, it expresses certainty. When you cannot understand something written by an author who has won the Nobel prize for literature, you should always assume that _your_ understanding is inadequate, and not that the writer needs to be corrected. Your "correction" reverses the order of cause and effect, and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that P.E. Dant answered to your satisfaction. I will try to elaborate.

Again, as Dant said the problem is cause and effect. Let's look at the sentences:

***"She must have been tired, for she fell asleep the moment she inclined her head."***

vs

***"She fell asleep the moment she inclined her head, for she must have been tired."***

The first version by the author tells us she must be tired (states a posit or cause) and then uses the proper coordinating conjunction ("for") to show the effect, which was that she feel asleep the moment she lay down.

In your version you reverse the logic and you state effect (her falling asleep) before cause (she must be tired). The logic of cause and effect are reversed in this case (which is really important because that's exactly why "for" is being used). It's not that you can't rearrange the sentence, you can, but you can't do it with those particular words and using that conjunction.

I hope that helps.